# Error connecting to database while installing informatica powercentre

Tags: database, informatica-powercenter

I'am trying to connect to oracle database(18c Express Edition) using correct[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6xot.jpg] credentials. Inside oracle database I'am able to connect with specific user. I have granted all roles and privileges as dba to that particular user. Even I'am providing the correct localhost and the port number that default 1521[https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVW1o.jpg]. But unable to connect to that database, it is showing the error [https://i.stack.imgur.com/yutXd.jpg]"Correct the database connection information and test the connection again". I tried connecting using JDBC connection string.It is also showing same error.Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Please add more information about your setup (version, OS ect.).

Comment: @SteffenMangold am using oracle 18c express edition database and Os is Windows 10

Comment: did you try -  1. tnsping from client to the DB ?   2. the user which is installing infa have correct --X privileges for those oracle client files.   3. PATH variable  is set.  4. jdbc is aded to library files.

Comment: @koushik sinharoy.yes the tnsping is ok.its not showing any error.i even tried the points you mentioned above.but dont know what is happening.

Comment: Customer jdbc string also not working? can you check your host file as well?